# FileAlreadyExistsException with MultipleOutputs

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm using Hadoop 2.5.1 on Ubuntu 14.04

Now that I'm trying to use MultipleOutputs class. The jobs can run properly on small data like 8 lines of input. But when I try running the data with 1000+ lines (not that's called big but bigger than 8 I think), the task failed and throw exception says

```
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException): /out/_temporary/1/_temporary/attempt_1430139159731_0055_m_000000_0/MYFOLDERNAME-m-00000 for client MY_MASTER/SLAVE_IP already exists
```

I'm running 2 nodes fully-distributed mode.

I also double check the hdfs before running the jobs that there's no existed file there.

Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are initializing the MultipleOutputs inside the reduce method. With small input reduce method is called only once and hence you are not facing this issue. When reduce method gets called multiple times in same task with different keys then the multiple output is getting intitalized multiple times giving the error.

Try to initialize the MultipleOutput inside configure() method.

Also try to comment out the combiner class.

Comment: Thanks for reply sir.
I'm doing something like this http://imgur.com/FGXELXE

and using mos.write() inside the reduce method.
What am I suppose to do to fix this?

Comment: @spacez that looks correct. Can you paste the driver class and the reducer code.

Comment: Here are the driver and reducer. Sorry that I could not show all of them for reasons, also the reducer method is quite long but I call the write() once at this part. Thanks.
http://i.imgur.com/zlAHfCk.jpg


http://i.imgur.com/pO6bNBo.jpg

Comment: No obvious reason. Can you try commenting out the Combiner class?

Comment: Removing Combiner class got something. For smaller data, I can run properly. For bigger data, the latter job (3rd job) throws exception says filenotfound. After digging into the issue, I found that the folder name (output from MultiOutput of the 2nd job) I used for ReadFile is xxxx-m-00000. But after commenting the reducer in 2nd job there's no xxxx-m-00000 anymore, there is only the -r-00000 (which has some differences and I would prefer -m-00000 if possible). Is there any other ways to solve this? Or I just have to use -m-00000. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Commenting the Combiner class off, I can run the job with bigger data successfully. However, when I increase the size of data even more, the error as in pic's shown. http://imgur.com/jQufI0N

From what I understand, is this related to non-sufficient local storage? Do I understand things right? Really thanks in advance for help.

Comment: I am not sure on that error. It could be because of local disk space issue.

Comment: It's fine, thanks for helping me solve the issue. Marked your answer already.